# Second order linear ODE boundary value problem at a single point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following definition of an initial boundary problem.

'If the given conditions are given at more than one point and the differential equation is of order two or greater, it is called a boundary value problem.'

I am given the following conditions.

$ y(1) = 0 ^ f'(1) = 0 $

Since both points are $(1, 0)$, does that mean  that this is not an initial boundary problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what "initial boundary" problem [b]means[/b]!  I suspect your problem is thinking that there is such a thing!  If you are given a second order differential equation with conditions at a single point, say, 0, is an **initial** condition.  If conditions are given at two different points, that is a **boundary** condition.  However, those conditions should be for the *same* function!  Do you mean y(1)= 0 and y'(1)= 0  or f(1)= 0 and f'(1)= 0?

Comment: @user247327  I see. Thanks.